# How to refer human and animal as "both of them"?

Tags: grammar, translation, word-choice, words, usage

Situation: Your friend shows a picture of her child playing with a dog and you want to say you have a soft spot for both of them. Is there any equivalent word for "both of them" in Japanese? I think I might say this 私はふたりに目がない
but I'm not sure. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 3):

Most naturally, I would say:

> 「**どっちも**かわいい。」 ("They're both cute!")

It is fairly unnatural to use 「ふたり」 in the situation in question.  I might not say it is impossible, but as a native spekaer, I can promise that it will sound pretty weird even to a big animal lover.

Answer (score 2):

Use 子{こ}達{たち} for group of children, dogs, cats or adorable animals.

> 「かわいい子達ですね。」
>
> "They are cute!"
>
> 「かわいい子達だな〜と思いました。」
>
> "I thought/felt they are cute!"

Above are expressions that make use of polite phrases i.e. 子達 and ですね. These expressions could vary when expressed by female speakers or expressed in other dialects.

**References**

- [子達 on Jisho.org](http://jisho.org/word/%E5%AD%90%E9%81%94)
- [子達 on Weblio辞書](http://www.weblio.jp/content/%E5%AD%90%E9%81%94)
- [ですね on Weblio辞書](http://www.weblio.jp/content/%E3%81%A7%E3%81%99%E3%81%AD)